# how put correct conditions in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Hello i need your help so i made xslt for my xml but i faced some problem

this is my xml

```
<ad>
<year>1965</year>
<make>Piper</make>
<model>Cherokee</model>
<color>Gold</color>
<description>
240 hours SMOH, dual Navomatics COMs, DME, new Cleveland brakes, great shape
</description>
<price>356874</price>
<seller phone="555-333-2222" email="jseller@www.axl.com">John Seller</seller>
<location>
<city>St. Joseph,</city>
<state>Missouri</state>
</location>
</ad>
```

this is my xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="planes_for_sale">
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>work</title>
    <body>
    </body>
    <h3>Piper brand Flights </h3>
  <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price after Discount</th>
    <th>Phone</th>

  </tr>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </table>
  </head>
  </html>
   </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ad">
  <tr>
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="model"/>

  </td>

   <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="year"/>

  </td>

   <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="color"/>

  </td>

   <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(description ,',','-')"/>

  </td>

   <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="(price) - (price)*30 div 100 "/>

  </td>

   <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(seller/@phone,'555-')"/>

  </td>
  </tr>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**i want put this condition but i did not know where i can put them**

a. flight should be Piper make (this one inside the xml in make element)

b. flight should have Navomatics (this one in the description)

c. price should be less than 300000 (This price should be after discount on actual price)

any help?? i will appreciate it...Thank you very much

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn that your XML and XSLT files have to be included in your question (and not on some suspicious file hoster). Also make sure that your question completes a [mcve]. Thanks for your understanding and use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61740759/edit) button to improve your question.

Comment: okay thank you i will fix it

Comment: Your XML does not have `planes_for_sale` so your 1st template will not be applied. It's hard to answer your question when a large part of relevant code seems to be missing.

Comment: @zx485 Please DO NOT edit OP's code. You don't know what it looks like (and I am quite sure it does NOT look like what you have assumed).

Answer (score 0):

it works now i add if condition

```
<xsl:if test="make='Piper' and contains(description,'Navomatics') ">
```

thank yyou very much for help